# How to use PFQuery in ios for beginner

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, parse-platform

I am searching about "How to implement PFquery in ios ?"

I am getting followings links. I am fresher in ios field and I don't understand that..

this  [link](https://www.parse.com/docs/osx/api/Classes/PFQuery.html) for discription of PFquery

this  [link](https://parse.com/tutorials/anypic) for discription of PFquery

Please Help me any one know any tutorial for learning and implementing in iphone app.

Comment: you are using parse freamwork ?

Comment: Yes PFQuery is of Parse framework..

Comment: I'd suggest reading through the [Parse iOS and OSX guide](https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#top/iOS)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"UserInfo"];
 [query selectKeys:@[@"FirstName"]];
 NSArray *results = [query findObjects:nil];
 NSLog(@"%@",[results description]);
```

[And Check this link its all about PFQuery](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios_guide#queries/iOS)

Answer (score 1):

Example:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"tempClass"];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
  if (!error) {
    // The find succeeded. The first 100 objects are available in objects
  } else {
    // Log details of the failure
    NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
  }
}];
```

Good starter: [Parse with TableView](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1DljjW3gSeM)